# How do I show that $f(x)=x^2 + x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Tags: analysis

I know how to show that $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous, but I am confused when it is $x^2 +x$

Comment: What process did you use to show that $x^2$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Please, add some details about where you find an obstacle.

Comment: My confusion was how to decide what to assign to delta, but John helped me below. Thank you! :)

Comment: You can use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick wise-guy answer: every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. Heine-Borel tells you that $[0, 1]$ is compact. So your function is unif. continuous on $[0, 1]$, hence on the subset $(0, 1)$.

Alternative: In general, doing an epsilon-delta proof for a differentiable function $f$ at a point $x$, you want to choose something like $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{f'(x)}$, assuming that $f'$ isn't changing too fast. A good bet is to say $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2f'(x)}$, and then say "but also, never pick $\delta > 1$ (or some other amount $A$ with the property that between $x-A$ and $x+A$, $f'(x)$ doesn't change by more than a factor of $2$". The case where $f'(x) = 0$ can be messy, but if you've seen the proof of continuity for $x^2$, you should be OK.

So what's that tell you? Well, your function has derivative $f'(x) = 2x + 1$ on the interval, i.e., the derivative is between $1$ and $3$. So you can safely choose $\delta = \epsilon/6$ to prove continuity at any point $x$ of the interval.

Comment: Thank you! that helps a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The collection of all uniformly continuous functions in a given interval form a vector space.